# Is there a way to accept multiple data types into a Java Scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am attempting to design code in java to accept any data type that comes up. For instance, if I ask a user a question, it doesn't matter if they input a string, a double, or an integer, it will be accepted and inputted into a variable. I know I can do this in python because you don't have to pre-define a variable's data type. Is there a way I can do this in Java?

Comment: The user always is inputting text, it's up to you to decide if you want to read it in some more helpful datatype but String always is an option.

Comment: Just take the input in the string using scanner.nextLine(); or scanner.next() as per your requirement.

Check if the string contains a decimal point(.). If it does, it's a double value. Check if the string consists of letters, if it does, it's a string, else an integer value.

Comment: This is a little simplistic and not really correct.  Testing a string like "Mr. Johnson" for a decimal point and assuming it's a double if it contains a "." is pretty error prone.  It's better to use the api calls like `Scanner.hasNextDouble()` because those are much more sophisticated and check correctly for types in a data stream.  In other words don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Scanner.next(Pattern)` method to test if your input matches something specific.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#next(java.util.regex.Pattern)

You can also just call `hasNextX()` with `if` statements to test if the input matches some type.  Here's a simple test I wrote a while ago while researching a different SO question.  This code uses scanner to test if the input is either a string or a double and parses appropriately.

```
  String test = " test test < 1.234 2.234 3.456 > more ";
  Scanner scan = new Scanner( test );
  while( scan.hasNext() ) {
     if( scan.hasNextDouble() ) {
        double i = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println( "Double: " + i );
     }
     else {
        String s = scan.next();
        System.out.println( "String: " + s );
     }
  }
```